How can I dereference a pointer in an eBPF program
Here is a very basic eBPF program.
I am trying to hook file deletion.
#define __TARGET_ARCH_arm64 

#include <linux/ptrace.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";

typedef struct {
        int counter;
} atomic_t;

struct filename {
        const char *name;
        const char *uptr;
        atomic_t refcnt;
        struct audit_names *aname;
        const char iname[0];
};

SEC("kprobe/do_unlinkat")
int BPF_KPROBE(do_unlinkat, int dfd, struct filename *name)
{
    const char *filename = BPF_CORE_READ(name, name);

    // This line causes the crash
    if (filename!=NULL && *filename=='t') return 1;

    bpf_printk("Deleting this file:%s", filename);
    return 0;
}

Everything works fine, except when I am trying do dereference filename pointer.
I get this error, at compilation time:
arg#0 reference type('FWD pt_regs') size cannot be determined: -22
0: R1=ctx() R10=fp0
; int BPF_KPROBE(do_unlinkat, int dfd, struct filename *name) @ test_ebpf.c:30
...
R3 invalid mem access 'scalar'
processed 11 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0

Can anyone explain me how I can access to filename content ?
bpf_printk manages to display this value...
Thanks

TL;DR. BPF_CORE_READ reads the value of the name->name pointer with CO-RE, but you need still need to copy the string from the kernel memory to the the BPF stack with bpf_probe_read_kernel_str.

Explanation
Your program retrieves a value from kernel memory with BPF_CORE_READ (syntactic sugar for bpf_probe_read_kernel) and attempts to dereference it. The verifier however rejects your program because it doesn't know anything about the value returned by BPF_CORE_READ and therefore treats it as a scalar (hence the R3 invalid mem access 'scalar' error) and not a pointer to a string.
The call to bpf_printk passes the verifier because this helper (bpf_trace_printk) includes runtime checks to handle such pointers (cf. bpf_bprintf_prepare).

Solution
The BPF CO-RE reference guide provides the solution. You need to call bpf_probe_read_kernel_str after BPF_CORE_READ to copy the string to the BPF stack. The example below passes the verifier on my system.
SEC("kprobe/do_unlinkat")
int BPF_KPROBE(do_unlinkat, int dfd, struct filename *name)
{
    char filename[40]; 
    const char *ptr;
    int ret;

    ptr = BPF_CORE_READ(name, name);
    ret = bpf_probe_read_kernel_str(filename, sizeof(filename), ptr);

    if (ret < 0 && *filename == 't')
        return 1;


Thanks for your answer. It compiles now. But there is something strange: If I try to remove a file starting by "t", the file is still deleted... Or it should not because I return 1...

Did you try to printk the first character to see if that matches your expectation?

Yes and I have tried to put a log debug message in test. The return 1 is executed...

What I want to do is to "cancel" the syscall when the filename starts by "t"

From the kprobes hook, you can change the return value of the syscall or even kill the userspace process, but I don't think you can skip the syscall. You may want to look at LSM BPF programs instead. Might be worth opening a new question in case others have better ideas.
